# why unique : true schema validation is not working in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here when I try to insert the data with proper validation it works. and when I post with wrong validation it also throws error as expected but when I use the email that was already present in my database and i had set the unique:true but it stores the document with same email.
What am i doing wrong
My model file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const Userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
        
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true, 
        unique:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})
const User =  new mongoose.model("user", Userschema)
module.exports = User
```

main file:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

router.post(
  "/createuser",
  [
    body("name", "please enter valid name").isLength({ min: 5, max: 15 }),
    body("password", "your password must be larger or equalt to 8 characters").isLength({ min: 8 }),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    try {
      const data = await User.create(req.body);
      res.json(data);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send("some error occured")
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Do any errors or warnings show up when you run the script with node? Did you add the "unique" attribute to the email field after creating some users, or was it "unique" from the start?

Comment: Yes, I added it later. I created a new db with unique form start and now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, If you add the unique after running the API to save the user in DB. It will not work. Because unique indexing runs the first time while creating collections. No worry, drop the data and run API. It should be working. If you don't want to drop the DB. The other solution is to write a migration task to create a unique index.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const createIndex = async () => {
  try {
    const url = 'paste your db url';
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
    const dbName = 'paste your db name';
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    await db.collection('users').createIndex(
      {email: 1 },
      { unique: true },
    );

    process.exit(1);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
};
createIndex();
```

Run the above code with 'node'.